# Redirect to same page - the page is in endless loop

Tags: html

I have made a huge mistake. I am working with a backend system, where I am only allowed to post simple html and CSS code.

I needed to make a redirect from page x to page y. Therefore I posted this code:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=site.com/page/page-x">
```

But I made a mistake, so I made the redirect to the same page. That means the page is just refreshing every 0.5 seconds. I cannot make it stop, so I can delete the code I made in the backed.

Can I stop the redirect in the inspector window in Chrome or Firefox, so I can delete the redirect code?

I cross my fingers somebody can help me.

Comment: `I cannot make it stop, so I can delete the code I made in the backed` - what does **modifying the backend** have to do with **a browser running it in the front end**? Ignore or close the browser (tab), and just do what you need to do in the backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling META REFRESH in the browser.

In Firefox, go to `about:config`, find `accessibility.blockautorefresh` and set it to **true**.

Hopefully it will prevent a page from refreshing.

Comment: You are the king for me right now. Thank you a lot, you really saved me. If you were here, I would give you a kiss and a basket of chocolates. Thank you a lot!